# Link para uma div em outra pagina não funciona

Tags: html, div, link

Eu tenho este codigo:

```
<div id="text"><p>A Intertráfego está disponível a ser alcançada a qualquer momento.
Saiba <a href="pedir_cotacao.html#map">onde estamos</a> e <a
href="pedir_cotacao.html#otherQuestion"> os nossos contactos </a></p></div>
```

O problema é que o link para o mapa não funciona, muda para a pagina correta mas não para a div que quero, e o outro link (pedir_cotacao#otherQuestion) funciona perfeitamente, já tentei inclusive uma div invisivel em cima do mapa e por o link para essa div e tb não dá. Alguma dica? Obgado

Comment: Você poderia postar seu código html dessa página **pedir_cotacao.html#map** ?

Comment: Acho que isso é resposta à sua pergunta.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314990/link-a-div-to-a-particular-section-on-a-different-page-in-html

Comment: Existe espaço suficiente por baixo da div (ou altura suficiente da div) para que ela fique no topo do ecrã? Por exemplo, imagine que a div "map" é a última da página e tem 200px de altura, se não houver espaço por baixo para que ocorra o scroll e fique no topo do ecrã, apenas irá ficar 200px da parte inferior do ecrã e assim parece que não funciona, mas na verdade funciona. Será que deu para entender?

Comment: Percebi, mas será que é este o caso? http://www.iwanttobesanta.com/order_quotation.html
O link está a ser feito na home page (index)

Comment: tanto http://www.iwanttobesanta.com/order_quotation.html#otherQuestion como o http://www.iwanttobesanta.com/order_quotation.html#map funcionam, qual o problema?

Comment: Os links estão no index. E se clicarmos no link para ir para o mapa ("...onde estamos..") apesar de irem os para a pagina correta não vai para a div do mapa

Comment: Percebi, acredito que o problema está no facto de que você está a usar divs absolutas. Reparei que o "#otherQuestion" também não funciona porque não está posicionando correctamente, embora pareça. Isso terá que ser feito com Jquery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972082/problem-with-html-anchor-in-absolute-div-300px-from-the-top

Comment: Obgado, mas porque diz que não estão posicionadas corretamente?

Comment: Porque ao abrir com a âncora "#otherQuestion", deveria posicionar a div no topo do ecrã uma vez que existe scroll para isso, porém não contece, fica a meio da página, logo não está a funcionar correctamente.

Answer (score 2):

O que impede de ser posicionado corretamente é a propriedade CSS `position: relative`.
Coloque os 2 elementos como `position: static`, ou sem essa definição, pois `static` é o padrão.

```css
#otherQuestion {
    /*position: relative; -> Remova */
    float: left;
    height: 450px;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 2px solid #1a1a1a;
}
#map {
    /*position: fixed; - Remova */
    width: 100%;
    height: 450px;
    /*bottom: 0; -> tb desnecessário */
    border: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="map" style="background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223); overflow: hidden; -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);">
```

Comment: penso que não iria resolver uma vez que a estrutura da página depende de um position relative, teria que mudar mais coisas.

Comment: por que depende? eu alterei aqui dinamicamente para static pelo DevToolbar e não mudou nada.